# How to Fix 'Object is possibly null' Error in Angular/TypeScript?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <section class="col-3">
        <h5 class="text-warning ml-3">Sort</h5>
        <select class="custom-select mb-3" (change)="onSortSelected($event.target.value)">
            <option *ngFor="let sort of sortOptions" [value] = "sort.value">{{sort.name}}</option>
            
        </select>
```

I am getting the following error in the ($event.target.value)  part value throws an error
: Angular error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'

```
 onSortSelected(sort: string){
  this.sortSelected = sort;
  this.getProducts();
}
```

Comment: `target` is typed as `EventTarget | null`, so Typescript will throw an error if you access a property from a possibly nullish object. You can use optional chaining `$event.target?.value` to avoid this error.

Comment: It's not clear what `onSortSelected` expects. Most likely, using `$event.target?.value` will work. Depending on what the fn expects, you might have to provide a default value (e.g: `$event.target?.value || ''`)

Comment: Either you only pass `$event` to the function or you set `strictTemplates` to false in the `tsconfig`. Using optional is highly not raccomended if not properly checked in the function's logic itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can add change `$event.target.value` to `$event.target?.value`
And then maybe you have to change the Type of the param in onSortSelected

```ts
onSortSelected(val: string): void {
  if (!val) return;
  
  this.sortSelected = sort;
  this.getProducts();
}
```

Or because of the error `property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ngtsc(2339)`

```html
<select class="custom-select mb-3" (change)="onSortSelected($any($event.target).value)">
    <option *ngFor="let sort of sortOptions" [value]="sort.value">{{sort.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I will add the codes related to onSortSelected, you can see above

Comment: now i get this error :roperty 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ngtsc(2339)

Answer (score 2):

Catch the value in your controller, send all object $event, like this:

```
<select (change)="onSortSelected($event)">
    <option
        *ngFor="let sort of sortOptions"
        [value]="sort.value">{{sort.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

In your controller:

```
onSortSelected(value: YourModel) {
    this.selected = value?.target?.value;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The `change` event emitter emits the `$event` variable with the information about the change event. `$event.target.value` is something which is provided by the DOM event, and not something which can be initialized by the developer.

Comment: Then the guy need to send the data like this: <select (change)="onSortSelected($event)">

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by doing this:

```
(change) = "onSortSelected($any($event.target).value)"
```

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the type of `$event` and see if target could be null, or if `target.value` could be null. If `$event` has a type of `{ target?: ...}` then you are going to get this error. It could also possibly be that $event itself is nullable. If you REALLY know that you will be getting a value here, you can use the `!` operator to tell typescript that the value will not be null, like `$event!.target.value` or `$event.target!.value`.